# exif_read_data suppressing IFD error

Tags: exif

Is there any way to suppress exif data 'Illegal IFD size' error? The following has not worked:

```
if (@exif_read_data($targetFile)) {
    $exif = @exif_read_data($targetFile);
}
// this also failed
if ($exif = @exif_read_data($targetFile)) {
    blah, blah
}
// as did this
$exif = @exif_read_data($targetFile);
if ($exif) {
```

Answer (score 0):

My only resolve to this was via my error handler function, here it is should anyone need it:

```
function error_report ($e_num, $e_mes, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars) {
    if (strpos($e_mes, 'exif_read_data') === false) {
        // report message
    }
}
set_error_handler ('error_report');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-catch in this case:

```
 try {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filePath);
 }
 catch (Exception $exp) {
    $exif = false;
 }
 if ($exif){
    ...
 }
```